# How can I fix being banned if I don't know why?

Tags: support

I am apparently banned from posting any kind of answer.  I only know of one instance I was told it was not a good answer. Even though it added to the previous answer.  If you don't tell me what the problem is I can't fix it.  I have been on-line since the 70's and have never had this problem, anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: This does seem strange. I can't find any downvoted answers from your account on any site. Do you maybe have multiple deleted ones? I think, to be able to post answers, you need people to upvote some of your posts, but I'll wait for confirmation on that one

Answer (score 7):

Of your 5 answers,

- 5 have quality-related flags (4 "not an answer", 1 "very low quality")
- 2 were deleted for their quality, 1 was deleted because the question was deleted.
- 1 has a downvote
- 0 have upvotes

Your answers themselves aren't that poorly written but they do come across as stabs in the dark, or for other distributions (with guesswork for Ubuntu), and several sections of existing answers are essentially telling the user what to Google for. Not unhelpful but not answer material. This is what comments are for (what you can do when you have 50 reputation).

Unfortunately you're stuck in a hard place. The ban is completely automated. [You have to overturn it yourself](https://askubuntu.com/help/answer-bans). The site moderators can't help you directly. [Not yet anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273258/moderator-override-on-automated-bans).

---

I will message a CM on your behalf to try and expunge some of the older answers contributing toward the ban but —assuming they want to help— please note that you'll need to improve the level of your answer to avoid stepping straight into another ban.

Comment: There seems to be some rogue punctuation at the end of your answer that you might want to clean up...

Comment: Accidentally deleted the opening square bracked for a link.

Comment: I thought this was to learn.  Google is not being used by these people or they wouldn't have to write the question.  Also the error message "Not accepting answers for this account." lead me to believe it was to whom I was answering.  Should say "accepting answers from your account" would have been much clearer.  OK, I will not answer any questions.